# How should I connect to .NET 1.1 Webservice from a .NET CF 3.5 Windows Application?

Tags: .net, web-services, compact-framework

I have an windows application in .NET Compact Framework 1.0. I have migrated the application to .NET CF 3.5 (VS 2008) using the .NET conversion wizard. The CF 1.0 application connects to a web service developed in .NET 1.1. When I tried to connect to the same web service in CF 3.5 application it results in "Remote Server is not responding (503)" error. Can anyone help me out in this? Also I compared the "References.cs" file of both versions. They are same. Is there any configuration change that I should I do in .NET 3.5 or VS 2008?

Thanks

Comment: You should upgrade to at least .NET 2.0 because .NET 1.1 had several bugs in XML Serialization and in XML processing in general. It's possible for those bugs to simply render a .NET 1.1 service incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the first thing to do is ensure that the web service is still running as expected, browsing to the definition on the server.

Next I would update the web reference from the WSDL definition to ensure that you have a good version of the Web Reference.

There are a few differences between 1.1 and 2.0/3.5 such as configuration of dynamic endpoints, but none should affect basic communications.

Otherwise, it should just work.  After all that is the idea of a web services is that there isn't a dependency on the type of server.